# Tunnel into multiple servers and establish port link

Tags: ssh, proxy, tunnel

I have create port link in my local system for a database for accessing it.

Working Case: When I have only one server as proxy I use.

ssh -L 5433:rds-server:5432 
Using this syntax I am able to connect to the rds-server:5432 from my local using: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/reports

Need help Case: When I have two servers as proxy

I have to ssh into proxy-server1 and from there ssh into proxy-server2 and access the rds-server:5432. I need a command so that I can tunnel two servers and create a link to the rds-server:5432 to my localhost:5433.

Comment: Is my answer a soltion?

Answer (score 0):

I expect you use key authentication:

Just run

```
ssh -L 5433:rds-server:5432 'ssh -L 5433:rds-server2:5432'
```

The server you connect to firstly will automatically run the command inside ''.

See here: https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh